# argv doesn't read < or > python

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argv

I'm using Python3 and I want to get **<** or **>** via **argv**. here is my code:

```
str_args = [ str(x) for x in argv[1:] ] #create sequence
cmd = ''
for i in argv[1:]: #create str
    cmd += i + ' '
path = 'cmd.txt'
file=open(path, "a")
file.write(cmd + '\n')
file.close()
```

here in for loop  I concatenate arguments to make a linux terminal command and write in a .txt file. I execute that command somewhere else. when I type < or > (greater than or less than), it only pass until < or >. example:

> echo 12 > test.txt

and it just get

> echo 12

and doesn't pass > test.txt
What should I do ? It works fine for non < or > examples. for example it pass a command like this well:

> ping 8.8.8.8 -c 2 -s 60

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `>` and `<` are treated specially by the shell, this has nothing to do with python because the shell strips them out before your code is called. Without quotes, the `>` means to send the output of the command to a file given as the next argument. In your case, stdout of the script will be *redirected* to the file `test.txt`.

To pass them as character strings you must either use quotes or the escape character:

```
# using quotes
python the_script.py echo 12 '>' test.txt

# using the escape character
python the_script.py echo 12 \> test.txt
```

Note: it's not just `>` and `<` you have to worry about. Characters such as `*` and a few others need to be protected, too. These are all mentioned in the bash man page (or the man page of whatever shell you're using).

Comment: it works thanks! but I use that argv to both run as a command and write to the file. now it correctly write to the file but it doesn't execute ! but I can handle this somewhere, do you a solution for both purposes?

Comment: @OmidEstaji: there's not enough information for me to understand what "doesn't execute" mean. If you have another question, I recommend you click the "ask question" button. Comments are for clarification, and you're asking a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Certain symbols such as `>` or `<` have a special meaning to POSIX shells and they are interpreted by the shell itself, and they are not passed as arguments. To fix this escape them by writing a backslash (`\`) before them such as: `python test.py a b c \> foo`. Another option is to put them in quotes (which is a recommended thing to do either way). Also, your code snippet contains a bug - it is missing an `import sys` and by `argv` you probably mean `sys.argv`.

Comment: thanks, it is just a small part of my code and that contains all imports.